# Silverlight on Linux / Mac

Tags: linux, silverlight, macos, html, moonlight

I have a big winforms app which I now rewrite as an HTML5 app for the sake of portability.

There is an important UI component with a lot of logic and BCL usage that will be very hard to rewrite as HTML/JS. I am thinking to have this component only in SL.

Looking 2 years ahead does this still give me portability?

The moonlight project seems stuck.
Apple may decide to have new rules or break some compatability.

Are these real risks or am I expected to have at least what I have today?

Comment: This question likely doesn't have an answer.  That being said: look around the web, how much Silverlight do you see?  And which way is the trend?  I personally wouldn't do any web development around SL given all the push with HTML5 and javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no absolute answer to this of course, it's purely opinion.

However, my advice is to stick to general standards as much as possible; as you say - SL may deprecate, Moonlight might not update again, Apple may completely drop flash support. Who knows ?

They are real risks, but you can program defensively - document your API thoroughly, consider writing a REST/WCF/SOAP interface that can provide the behaviour your program needs.

You're right to be concerned that there are risks basically!

Comment: It is my understanding Microsoft is already encouraging developers not to use SL on the desktop. We *nix users and developers have no interest in Mono or Moonlight.

Comment: Rob's right, MS looks as though it's moving away from Silverlight.

Comment: Sadly, although that may be knee-jerk response to people's worry about SL not being used in the windows 8 preview. I try to be optimistic though ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy decision to take. For example, if you are targeting Windows users you can successfully go with Silverlight.

Consider reading this [post](http://davybrion.com/blog/2011/03/why-were-going-with-html5-instead-of-silverlight/) and looking at the process that lead to the decision (*for them it wasn't Silverlight but according to your needs, for you may suit fine*).